# OAuth ServletException with RestEasy

Tags: servlets, oauth, oauth-2.0, jboss7.x, resteasy

code on: JBoss 7.1.1.Final, JEE6, JSF2, using resteasy oauth:

on web.xml:

```
   <context-param>
        <param-name>oauth.provider.provider-class</param-name>
        <param-value>com.ostudio.dbo.rest.OAuthMyProvider</param-value>
    </context-param>

    <servlet>
      <servlet-name>OAuth</servlet-name>
      <servlet-class>org.jboss.resteasy.auth.oauth.OAuthServlet</servlet-class>
    </servlet>

    <servlet-mapping>
      <servlet-name>OAuth</servlet-name>
      <url-pattern>/oauth/*</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>
```

on my project.war:
WEB-INF/classes/com/ostudio/dbo/rest/OAuthMyProvider.class

when I call localhost:8080/dbo/oauth server shows:

```
javax.servlet.ServletException: oauth.provider.provider-class class com.ostudio.dbo.rest.OAuthMyProvider not found
    org.jboss.resteasy.auth.oauth.OAuthUtils.getOAuthProvider(OAuthUtils.java:176)
    org.jboss.resteasy.auth.oauth.OAuthServlet.init(OAuthServlet.java:105)
    org.jboss.as.jpa.interceptor.WebNonTxEmCloserValve.invoke(WebNonTxEmCloserValve.java:50)
    org.jboss.as.web.security.SecurityContextAssociationValve.invoke(SecurityContextAssociationValve.java:153)
    org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:102)
    org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:368)
    org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.process(Http11Processor.java:877)
    org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Protocol$Http11ConnectionHandler.process(Http11Protocol.java:671)
    org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$Worker.run(JIoEndpoint.java:930)
    java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:619)
```

Please help me to resolve this without put the class on jboss/lib

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
<context-param>
    <param-name>oauth.provider.provider-class</param-name>
    <param-value>org.jboss.resteasy.auth.oauth.OAuthMemoryProvider</param-value>
</context-param>
```